# How to do downgrade watchman version using home-brew in macOS?

Tags: react-native, macos, npm, homebrew, watchman

I am trying to `downgrade` the latest `watchman` version to previous version. I tried to follow source code replacement method but it dosen't work for me. Below are me my system configurations

```
System:
    OS: macOS 12.4
    CPU: (6) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8500 CPU @ 3.00GHz
    Memory: 59.54 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 17.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.5.5 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2022.07.04.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 15.5, macOS 12.3, tvOS 15.4, watchOS 8.5
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32
      Build Tools: 26.0.2, 28.0.3, 29.0.2, 29.0.3, 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 31.0.0, 31.0.0, 31.0.0
      System Images: android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-30 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
      Android NDK: 22.1.7171670
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.2 AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683
    Xcode: 13.4.1/13F100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 1.8.0_252 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: Not Found
    react-native: ^0.68.0 => 0.68.0
```

Answer (score 1):

*While installing packages with HomeBrew might be easy, unfortunately, there isn't an out-of-the-box simple solution to downgrading.*

---

### Scenario 1

If the older version of `watchman` you’re looking to switch back to has been installed by Homebrew in the past, you’re lucky. You can see which versions are locally available by issuing:

```
brew info watchman
```

Pick one of the existing local versions and switch to it via:

```
brew switch watchman <version>
```

**DONE!**

---

### Scenario 2

This is where things get a little more involving. Since Homebrew doesn’t provide a command to arbitrarily select a version to install, you have to manually find the version you need in Homebrew’s GitHub repository, copy the URL to it and pass it as an argument for manual installation.

##### ***Step 1***

Go to https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/find/master and type the name of the package you are looking for (`watchman` in your case):

[image: GitHub Homebrew page]

**Select the one ending in `.rb`!**

##### ***Step 2***

Click on `History` and find the version you are trying to downgrade to.

[image]

When you find the desired version, click on the `Commit ID` to view the details. (I will be using `fcd0342` as an example)

##### ***Step 3***

Click on the 3 dots and select `View File`

[image]

##### ***Step 4***

Click on `RAW` and copy the URL

[image]

##### ***Step 5***

Once you have the URL, execute this command:

```
brew install <raw-url>
```

**Cheers**